# designing application with backbone model and collection

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns, backbone.js

I'm trying to write my application using backbone and I'm fairly new to it. My application is basically showing user all of his photos and albums. I have some questions regarding the design of it.

To start with photo is an obvious candidate for model. so

```
var Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({})
```

then I have created a collection of photos.

```
var PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({})
```

This is for showing user "all photos", "photos uploaded on specific date" etc. ( notice its different than album )

Now my question is regarding albums, Would album be a model or collection?

As in album view, I'll be showing user all of his albums in grid layout with number of photos and album names and some other properties. So It makes sense to have album as Backbone model and collection of albums as Backbone collection.

But then when user clicks on album, I have to request all the photos inside that album. So, then album becomes a collection. But if I write album as collection, how do I represent a set of albums? would it be a collection of collections?

I hope it doesn't sound confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, a `Backbone.Collection` should map to one REST collection resource, and a `Model` to a one item in that collection. It's not strictly necessary, but large parts of Backbone are built around this way of thinking. Here's an example:

```
/photos    -> PhotoCollection
/photos/id -> Photo
/albums    -> AlbumCollection
/albums/id -> Album
```

If you have a clear RESTful structure like this, then I suggest you build your model structure to mirror it.

When you start building *relations* between different models, Backbone is not so opinionated, and you're free to set things up the way you want. Often it's simplest to think of relations between different models in terms of `is` and `has` relations. In you case it's a little bit tricky, because one could think that `Album is a collection of photos`, but also that `Album has photos`.

I would lean towards a `has` relationship here, mainly because an `Album` probably is more than just a collection of photos - it will have a title and other such properties of its own. In RESTful terms a collection cannot have any properties of its own.  So we say that `Album has a PhotoCollection`.

Let's say these are your `Photo` and `PhotoCollection`:

```
var Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var PhotoCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Photo,
  filterByDate: function(date) {
    //just some method
    return this.filter(function(photo) { return photo.get('date') === date; });
  }
});
```

And similarly an `Album` and `AlbumCollection`.

```
var Album = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function(attributes) {
    //make model.photos a PhotoCollection and initialize it with passed photos
    this.set('photos', new PhotoCollection(attributes.photos || []);
  }
});

var AlbumCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Album
});
```

Then you can access album's photos just like you would any other collection of photos:

```
album.get('photos').filterByDate('2012-12-24');
```

If you need the albums `PhotoCollection` to have different behavior from a normal `PhotoCollection`, you can simply extend from base collection and use it instead.

```
var AlbumPhotoCollection = PhotoCollection.extend({ ... });
```

It's hard to speculate further without knowing more about how your application looks, but in any case this would feel like a natural way of doing it.

Comment: Really well written and well thought out answer. Thanks a lot.